How to save the icon color when adding an item to Favorites in Flutter?
I'm trying to create a feature for adding Item to the Favorites screen via provider.
When you click on the icon, the color changes to green, the item is added and saved on the Favorites screen, BUT after a few seconds the icon color becomes gray again, as if the Item is no longer in the Favorites, although it is there.
Here is my code
    void main() {
 runApp(
    OverlaySupport(
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SubscriptionStatusProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => FavoritesProvider()),
        ],
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            final favoritesProvider = Provider.of<FavoritesProvider>(context, listen: false);
            favoritesProvider.loadFavorites();
            return const APP();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
 );
}

class FavoritesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
 List<Favoritable> _favorites = [];

 List<Favoritable> get favorites => _favorites;

 void addToFavorites(Favoritable item) {
    _favorites.add(item);
    _saveFavorites();
    notifyListeners();
 }

 void removeFromFavorites(Favoritable item) {
    _favorites.remove(item);
    _saveFavorites();
    notifyListeners();
 }

 bool isFavorite(Favoritable item) {
    return _favorites.contains(item);
 }

 // Load favorites from shared preferences
 Future<void> loadFavorites() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final favoritesJson = prefs.getString('favorites');
    if (favoritesJson != null) {
      final favoritesList = json.decode(favoritesJson) as List;
      _favorites = favoritesList.map((item) => Favoritable.fromJson(item)).toList();
      notifyListeners();
    }
 }

 // Save favorites to shared preferences
 Future<void> _saveFavorites() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final favoritesJson = json.encode(_favorites.map((item) => item.toJson()).toList());
    await prefs.setString('favorites', favoritesJson);
 }
}

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime selectedDate;
  const Screen({super.key, required this.selectedDate});

  @override

  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ScreenState createState() =>
      _ScreenState(selectedDate: selectedDate);
}

class _ScreenState extends State<AllDATAsScreen> {
  late final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  late Map<String, bool> expansionStates = {};
  DateTime? selectedDate;
  final int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool _isLoading = false; // Add this boolean variable to track loading state
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedDate = widget
        .selectedDate; // Initialize selectedDate with the widget's selected date
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey, // Add the GlobalKey to the Scaffold
      appBar: AppBar(
        //title: const Text('APP'),
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.title),
        titleSpacing: -1,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/Images/Fav.png'),
        ),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                    Color.fromRGBO(1, 203, 11, 0.75)),
                strokeWidth: 5,
                //semanticsLabel: 'Loading',
                semanticsLabel: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading,
                //semanticsValue: 'Loading',
                semanticsValue: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading,
              ),
            ) // Show circular progress indicator when loading
          : StreamBuilder<List<DATA>>(
              stream: _DATAStreamController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                          Color.fromRGBO(1, 203, 11, 0.75)),
                      strokeWidth: 5,
                      //semanticsLabel: 'Loading',
                      semanticsLabel: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading,
                      //semanticsValue: 'Loading',
                      semanticsValue: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading,
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Failed to load data'),
                  );
                } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                  return Center(
                    //child: Text('No data available'),
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.nomatchesavailable),
                  );
                } else {
              ....
               ....
                ....
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ExpansionPanelList(
                      expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      children:
                   ......
                   ......
                   ......
                        List<DATA> DATAs = entry.value;
                        Widget panelBody = Column(
                          children: DATAs.map<Widget>((DATA) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
    final favoritesProvider = Provider.of<FavoritesProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final isFavorite = favoritesProvider.isFavorite(DATA);
    if (isFavorite) {
      favoritesProvider.removeFromFavorites(DATA);
    } else {
      favoritesProvider.addToFavorites(DATA);
    }
 },
 child: Icon(
    Icons.star,
    color: Provider.of<FavoritesProvider>(context).isFavorite(DATA) ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
 ),
)
              ),
            ],
          )
...........
...........
...........


Try using async and await before calling the loadfavorite method
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 

  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(
    OverlaySupport(
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
         ..........
        ],
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) async {
            final favoritesProvider = Provider.of<FavoritesProvider>(context, listen: false);
            await favoritesProvider.loadFavorites(); // Wait for favorites to load
            return const APP();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


Tried this. The same behaviour

can u post the error log u are getting

There is no errors in the console. The behaviour is next. When I tap on star icon the color changes to green and item is adding to the Favorites screen. But after few seconds the color of the star icon change back to grey

This part of code
onTap: () {
final favoritesProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
final isFavorite = favoritesProvider.isFavorite(DATA);
if (isFavorite) {
favoritesProvider.removeFromFavorites(DATA);
} else {
favoritesProvider.addToFavorites(DATA);
}
},
child: Icon(
Icons.star,
color: Provider.of(context).isFavorite(DATA) ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
),
